# UTI doesn't seem to be saved properly

Tags: objective-c, uti

I have an app that should try to save Markdown files. This is the relevant portions from my Info.plist:

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
    <array>
        <string>md</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
    <string>icon.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>Markdown document</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>net.daringfireball.markdown</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
    <string>Owner</string>
    <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
    <string>MyDocument</string>
    <key>NSExportableAs</key>
    <array>
        <string>Microsoft Word Document</string>
        <string>RTF</string>
        <string>HTML</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSExportableTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>net.daringfireball.markdown</string>
        <string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>
        <string>public.rtf</string>
        <string>public.html</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

As you can see I also need the app to be able to export to doc, html and rtf.

Here is the UTExportedTypeDeclarations:

```
<dict>
    <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
    <array>
        <string>public.source</string>
    </array>
    <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
    <string>Markdown document</string>
    <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
    <string>net.daringfireball.markdown</string>
    <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
    <dict>
        <key>public.filename-extension</key>
        <array>
            <string>md</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Now when I save a document in my app, and then run `mdls` on the file I get:

```
kMDItemContentType             = "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge8043a"
kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "dyn.ah62d4rv4ge8043a",
    "public.data",
    "public.item"
)
```

Furthermore my app doesn't seem to be able to open the files it previously saved and gives an error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The autosaved document
>   “test10.md” could not be reopened. " UserInfo=0x102210bf0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=The autosaved document “test10.md” could not
>   be reopened. }

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it recognize my UTI properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that your conforms-to is incorrect. You need to have a super-type from the physical and the functional trees.

There are many outdated things in the documentation, please see my writeup about what parts you really need nowadays. For example you don't need the exportable types any more: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/09/fun-with-uti/

regarding import/export. It depends if this app owns the file type. If it does it should export it. If not it should import it. Of all the apps exporting a type IIRC the latest one wins. Any app that is able to read your type should import it. Also apps that state that they are able to work with UTIs upwards from yours can open the file. e.g. if your format conforms to plain text, then TextEdit can also open it.

Also with your experimenting you might have inadvertenly messed up your launch services UTI registry. My article mentions a way to clean it.

Comment: Yeah, adding `public.item` to my `UTTypeConformsTo` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here, but if the types can already be on your system (which these two seem likely to be) maybe you should be importing them type instead of exporting them?

So instead of `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` these should be in `UTImportedTypeDeclarations` array.

from [UTI overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH204-SW1)

> If your code relies on third-party UTI types that may not be present on the system, you should declare those UTIs as imported types in your bundle.

Comment: Question then is, what happens if some of my users don't have the type installed?

Comment: Documentation says:  "An imported UTI declaration is used to declare a type that the bundle does not own, but would like to see available on the system. For example, say a video-editing program creates files using a proprietary format whose UTI is declared in its application bundle. If you are writing an application or plugin that can read such files, you must make sure that the system knows about the proprietary UTI, even if the actual video-editing application is not available. To do so, your application should redeclare the UTI in its own bundle but mark it as an imported declaration."

Comment: Ah, looks like there was another missing piece that you got above. Glad you got it working.